# How to persist a child entity based on a prent entity with Doctrine/Symfony 3

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I'm having problem when I'm trying to persist an entity "Nursery_staff" that extends entity "user". I'have created the entity User and when I want to extend this "user" entity (create a nursery_staff entity based on the current user) I have this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email, password, born_on, created_at, updated_at, is_archived, is_validated, roles, discr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, "2016-11-30 13:11:51", null, 0, 0, "a:1:{i:0;s:9:\"ROLE_USER\";}", "nurserystaff"]:
```

Because he tries to persist a new user and the first name cannot be null.

There's my code :

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){
// User have chosen an existing Nursery
            $choice = $request->request->get('nursery_choice');
            if($choice)
            {
                // Current user
                $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

                // Retrieve the nursery from $choice integer
                $nursery = $this->getDoctrine()
                                ->getRepository('VSMyChildBundle:Nursery')
                                ->findOneBy(array('id' => $choice));

                // We create a new entry in the nursery_staff table
                $nurseryStaff = new NurseryStaff();
                $nurseryStaff->setRole('MANAGER');
                $nurseryStaff->setNursery($nursery);

                // We save this nursery Manager
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($nurseryStaff);
                $em->flush();
                return new JsonResponse(array('nursery' => $choice));
            }

            return new JsonResponse(array('Nothing to show'));
}
```

And there are my entities : 
-> USER

```
<?php

namespace VS\MyChildBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VS\MyChildBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="You already have an account with this email.")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=2,
     *     max=100,
     *     minMessage = "Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.",
     *     maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters."
     * )
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=2,
     *     max=100,
     *     minMessage = "Your last name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.",
     *     maxMessage = "Your last name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters."
     * )
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=6,
     *     max=100,
     *     minMessage = "Your email must be at least {{ limit }} characters long.",
     *     maxMessage = "Your email cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters."
     * )
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * Used to validate user's input
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="born_on", type="date", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    protected $bornOn;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_archived", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isArchived = false;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_validated", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isValidated = false;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserAddress", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $userAddresses;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $medias;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    protected $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
```

And nursery staff:

```
<?php

namespace VS\MyChildBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * NurseryStaff
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="nursery_staff")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VS\MyChildBundle\Repository\NurseryStaffRepository")
 */
class NurseryStaff extends User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="staff_role", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * @var Nursery
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nursery", inversedBy="staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_nursery_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $nursery;
```

Also, I would like to ask if my inheritance mapping is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: So many things wrong.  Time to roll up your sleeves and do some research.  Try here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php and here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Comment: Ok, but the doctrine documentation about inheritance has few examples ...

Comment: Partly because I think the doctrine documentation assumes you understand the basics of php  inheritance.  Ask yourself exactly what this line actually does: $nurseryStaff = new NurseryStaff($user); and you might get the idea.  And I'm not trying to be overly snarky.  But it's difficult to teach someone how fix a car engine if they don't know how to open the hood.

Comment: I would listen to @Cerad 's comments. There are definitely a number of issues with your code. For example, I even notice for NurseryStaff Entity you have `setRole` AND `setRoles` setters; one of those must be redundant!

Comment: setRole is Nursery staff setters that defines what kind of employer the user is. setRoles is the property for autorisation in symfony.